# Why does an element styled with "height: 100%" appears to be > 100%?

Tags: css, browser

I have a page where while the page loads, I put an **absolute DIV** over all of my content with "`height:100%`" that states "the page is loading...".

However, it appears from the scrollbar that the height of the page is 100% + the height of the content.

This immediately goes away once the page loads and the overlay absolute positioned DIV is set to `display:none`.

This happens in Firefox 3, Chrome, IE6.

**Any ideas on how to make height:100%, just 100% and not more?**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style type="text/css">
         * html, * body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
            #message {background: black; height: 100%; left: 0; opacity: 0.15; position: absolute; top: 0%; width: 100%}
            #loading {height: 100%; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 45%; width: 100%; z-index: 2}
            #loading p {background: white; border: 2px solid #666; width: 180px}
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="grayout"></div>
     <div id="loading"><p>Page is loading...</p></div>
     <div id="content">
     // content is dynamically loaded into this div via AJAX
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**: it appears the problem is that I have "top:45%".  How do move that DIV to the center of the page (since it's a "page is loading message") without causing this same problem all over again?

Comment: Note that `* body` triggers all browsers and not just the IE.

Comment: Can you add the HTML and any other CSS you're using.

Comment: I tried the html in the question and didn't see any weird issues with scrollbars or content height.

Comment: Never said it was an IE specific problem. Said it happens in Firefox 3, Chrome and IE6 ... the browsers I have access too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that element has vertical padding or margin, it’s added to the height of the block according to the CSS specification (see the [visual formatting model for absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height)).

---

**Edit**   The `top:45%` is moving your element 45% down. Remove it (`top:0`) or set the element’s height to `auto` (default value).

Comment: Well then we need some code or the page itself to see what’s causing this behavoir.

Comment: You're right, the "top:45%" is the cause of the problem.  How do I move that DIV down the page so that it's not at the top without causing the same problem as before?

Comment: I figured it out, by removing the height:100% from the #loading DIV makes it work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
* html, * body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Which should remove all padding and margins from the page as well.

Comment: I've set padding/margin to 0 - still same problem

Comment: This is the right answer.  The height:100% on the html and body will cause these to fill 100%, which means the div which the body contains can go 100%.  With just the margin/padding, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: That doesn't work because my content is longer than a page long. So by doing overflow:hidden - that makes the scrollbar disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the flow of the page, so the div probably isn't being fitted behind the content. Why is the container div being absolutely positioned in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Almost always, I start my CSS with the following line:

```
* {padding:0; margin:0}
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: I've set the padding/margin to 0 and this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Re: // A LOT of content is dynamically loaded via AJAX

Does any of the dynamic data have unbreakable lines, or perhaps images or text that would exceed the space?

Comment: "images that would exceed the space"  - exceed what space? The "content" DIV grows and shrinks based on the amount of content. Much like this web page grows by the more answers that are posted.  I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Your "loading" div is the full height of the window, and it's positioned 45% from the top, so it overflows the window by 45%, giving you a scroll bar.

Try moving it to the top of the page and centering the text vertically.

Answer (score -1):

Ha posted HTML caused an issue without intro text..

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div style="height: 100%; background-color: blue;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```